# Does Inverting Weak Equivalences in Top Identify Homotopy Equivalent Maps?

Tags: homotopy-theory

I think this is supposed to be true. Given maps $f_t:X\to Y$ for $t\in[0,1]\,,$ does $f_0$ get identified with $f_1$ in the category of topological spaces obtained by localizing at weak equivalences? There should be a third space $Z$ with appropriate maps as in the diagram (3) in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VB, but I can't seem to see what the space should be.

Comment: Terminology: maps can be homotopic, not homotopy equivalent. Spaces, in contrast, can be homotopy equivalent, but not homotopic.

Comment: Is it true but you should not use the theory of left/right multiplicative systems to localise w.r.t. weak homotopy equivalences.

Answer (score 1):

Let $i_0,i_1:X \rightarrow X \times I$ be the two inclusion maps $x \mapsto (x,0)$ and $x \mapsto (x,1)$.

We know that $i_0 = i_1$ in the homotopy category (hint: draw and stare at a diagram containing the maps $\pi: X \times I \rightarrow X$, $i_1$ and $i_0$ somehow).

From this we can deduce that $H \circ i_0 = H \circ i_1$ in the homotopy category and thus that $f = g$.

$H$ being the homotopy $X \times I \rightarrow X$.